# MYSQL - SELECT NULL otherwise latest DATE per group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in my database:

```
| ID   | FK_ID  | MODEL | DATE              | 
+------+--------+-------+-------------------+
|1     | 11     | m1    |NULL               |
|2     | 11     | m1    |NULL               |
|3     | 11     | m2    |2019-05-08 12:04:24|
|4     | 11     | m2    |2019-05-08 12:07:43|
|5     | 11     | m2    |2019-05-08 12:08:37|
|6     | 11     | m3    |2019-05-08 12:13:19|
|7     | 11     | m3    |NULL               |
|8     | 12     | m7    |2019-05-08 12:04:14|
```

**I want to get the latest DATE of each MODEL, but if the DATE is null for a MODEL then I want to get the NULL instead of latest date.**

**Expected Output**

```
| MODEL | DATE              |
+-------+-------------------+
| m1    |NULL               |
| m2    |2019-05-08 12:08:37|
| m3    |NULL               |
```

I tried the below query:

```
SELECT MODEL, DATE FROM MODEL_TABLE
WHERE FK_ID = 11 AND (DATE IN ( 
    SELECT MAX(DATE)
    FROM MODEL_TABLE
    GROUP BY MODEL
) OR DATE IS NULL)
GROUP BY MODEL;
```

But I am getting the below result:

**Actual Output (Wrong)**

```
| MODEL | DATE              |
+-------+-------------------+
| m1    |NULL               |
| m2    |2019-05-08 12:08:37|
| m3    |2019-05-08 12:13:19|
```

Can someone let me know how can correct the query to fetch the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count(*)`  counts all rows, `count(date)` counts non-null values. If they are the same, no null exists, i.e. return max(date), else return null.

```
SELECT MODEL, case when count(*) = count(DATE) then max(DATE) end
FROM MODEL_TABLE
group by MODEL
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select model,
       (case when count(*) = count(date) then max(date) end) as max_date
from model_table mt
group by model;
```

You can write the condition in other ways.  This might seem more intuitive for what you are doing:

```
       (case when count(date is null) = 0 then max(date) end) as max_date
```

Comment: For once I typed faster!